# How can I develop screen have tabs in android 4 like in skype contacts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

How can i create screen in android 4 have image and tabs like in skype contact as image below:

[image]

thank you for help.

Comment: Make your own custom tabs (for example by using radiobuttons)

Comment: Maybe no answer for me. Now i create two button with fragment for android 4.